# Percentage calculation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentage

I have columns `RSL` and `SUMofRSL`. I have tried calculating the percentage but it returns either 100% or 0%. In some instances it is a wrong calculation since it shows 0% . Below are the examples for your reference.

```
RSL     SUMofRSL    Percentage
------------------------------
 2          2         100%
 1          2           0%
48         96           0%
10         10         100%
```

I have used

```
([RSL] / [SumOfRSL]) * 100
```

Comment: Try `[RSL]*100/[SumOfRSL]` to avoid integer truncation down to 0 before multiplying.

Comment: What **datatype** are your columns? If you have `INT` values, you're performing INT division - which doesn't return any fractional values - you need to use `([RSL] * 1.0 / [SumOfRSL]) * 100.0` to convert these values to `DECIMAL` so that you get fractional values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data types of `RSL` and `SumOfRSL` are integers you will need to cast the columns to a data type that supports decimal places.

For example:-

```
(CAST([RSL] AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) / CAST([SumOfRSL] AS DECIMAL(10, 4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The division of two Integer factors will be another Integer. At least one of your factors must be decimal type if you want that the result be decimal. (See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms175009.aspx))

You can CAST one or both of your values as Kane suggested.